# ajax call back function

Tags: 7

i am using drupal 7

i am trying to add a button within form and successful.  now i want to call a function when someone click on that button

here is my code.

```
function clicktell_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //print_r($form);

    if($form_id=='user_register_form') {
        $form['add_button'] = array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value' => 'Verifynow',
            '#ajax'> array (
                'callback' => '_udr_ajax_handler',
                'progress' => FALSE,
            ),
        );


    }
}

function _udr_ajax_handler($form, &$form_state) {
    echo "hello "; exit;
}
```

But this is not working fine. 
Does anybody tell me how to solve this 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed equal sign '=' near '#ajax'.